# Elasticsearch Exception - Open Distro Alert

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I've installed [OpenDistro](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/) on my elastic search master node for the alerts. [RPM](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/rpm/) is used to install the plugin. After successfull installation of plugin ES is restarted but it shows the following error.

### Logs

```
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM[2019-03-13T12:05:55,977][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elastic-master-a1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PMorg.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PMCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:607) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:464) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:156) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:338) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    ... 6 more
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PMCaused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:598) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:464) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:156) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:338) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    ... 6 more
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PMCaused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: opendistro_security.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath or opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath must be set if transport ssl is reqested.
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.initSSLConfig(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:363) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.<init>(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:164) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.OpenDistroSecuritySSLPlugin.<init>(OpenDistroSecuritySSLPlugin.java:206) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin.<init>(OpenDistroSecurityPlugin.java:222) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:598) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:464) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:156) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:338) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
3/13/2019 1:05:55 PM    ... 6 more
```

Apparently it is caused because `opendistro_security.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath` or `opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath` is not set. But I have checked the config file for elasticsearch i-e `config/elasticsearch.yml` and it show the following contents (It can be seen that `opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath`) is set.

### elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

# minimum_master_nodes need to be explicitly set when bound on a public IP
# set to 1 to allow single node clusters
# Details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17288
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

######## Start OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Configuration ########
# WARNING: revise all the lines below before you go into production
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled: true
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
opendistro_security.allow_default_init_securityindex: true
opendistro_security.authcz.admin_dn:
  - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test, C=de

opendistro_security.audit.type: internal_elasticsearch
opendistro_security.enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
opendistro_security.check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
opendistro_security.restapi.roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"]
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3
######## End OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Configuration ########
```

Comment: And you have that file named `esnode-key.pem` on disk?

Comment: @Val yes I have the `esnode-key.pem` file on disk.

Comment: And it is properly located in the config directory ?

Comment: Yes the pem files are located under config directory.

Comment: elasticsearch-opendistro created for having a specific fork for questions

Comment: could you show your docker-compose file? or what you're using?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this because you haven't set the ssl setup to opendistro, or else you can comment everything in your security section and restart opendistro. simply you can disable the security and start again